# How can I use Data Binding with ProgressBar?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-progressbar

I'm trying to use `DataBinding` for a `ProgressBar`, but I didn't know how

this is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="addActivity"
            type="com.khairo.dallasadmin.view.addScreenSaver.AddScreenSaver" />

        <variable
            name="saverModel"
            type="com.khairo.dallasadmin.model.addScreenSaver.AddScreenSaverModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.addScreenSaver.AddScreenSaver">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_230sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:onClick="@{()->addActivity.selectImage()}"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_25sdp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:text="@string/send_image"
            android:background="@drawable/carve_blue"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:onClick="@{()->addActivity.sendImage()}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_15sdp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

as you see I added the

> layout, data and variable to xml code

What I have to do in the model now?

Thank you so much <3

Comment: What do you want to do with the Progressbar?

Comment: I want to use it for let the user know the the app is loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For progressBar you need to do the following:

**First:** 
You should **import View** to be able to handle visibility of your progressBar within your data tag as below:

```xml
<data>
.....
import type="android.view.View"/>
<data>
```

**Secondly:** 
You should add **isLoading** variable to your Model of type Boolean. This **isLoading** variable is changed according to your business, so when you need your progressBar is visible you keep it as **true**.

To make it work smoothly, you should make it like Observable. you can do so by making your model extends BaseObservable

> public class *yourmodel* extends BaseObservable

then you should generate getter and setter for **isLoading** as follows:

```java
     @Bindable
     public boolean isLoading() {
          return isLoading;
     }
     public void setLoading(boolean loading) {
          isLoading = loading;
          notifyPropertyChanged(BR.loading);
     }
```

**Note**: You may need to build your project to generate **BR** file.

You can check this model for [file](https://github.com/MustafaKhaled/AndroidNanoDegree-PopularMovieStage2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/popularmoviestage1/mustafa/example/com/popularmoviestage1/model/Movie.java) more details

Your **isLoading** field now should be Observable

**Thirdly:**

You should add the visibility attribute based on the value of `isLoading`.

```xml
 <ProgressBar
        ..........
        ..........
        android:visibility="@{addActivity.isLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: it is worked when     var isLoading= true
, but I could not make it gone?!!!

Comment: make sure you have imported View
 <data> <import type="android.view.View"/></data>

Comment: <data>
        <variable
            name="addActivity"
            type="com.khairo.dallasadmin.view.addScreenSaver.AddScreenSaver" />

        <variable
            name="saverViewModel"
            type="com.khairo.dallasadmin.viewModel.addScreenSaver.AddViewModel" />

        <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>

Comment: I will edit my answer includes the solution of your problem

Comment: okay check this please 
addScreenSaverBinding.testing= AddScreenSaverModel("", "")
        addScreenSaverBinding.testing!!.setLoading(true)
//// is it right